# How do I get rid of authentication login dialog when opening MS Office docs from a WebDAV server?

Tags: authentication, ms-office, webdav

I have an IT Hit WebDAV server which is using Basic+SSL. Each time I open MS Office document the login dialog pops up. How do I make it to be displayed only during first access and not shown each next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Office applications always ask for the authentication when used with Basic or Digest authentication. This is a Microsoft Office and Microsoft Mini-redirector limitation and there are no workaround in case your server is using Basic or Digest.

However, if you check "Remember my password" check-box it will still display the login dialog, but the user name and password will be already filled-in, so you just click "OK".

Here are some options to consider if you need to totally suppress login dialog with Microsoft Office:

- Use NTLM or Kerberos authentication. In case of NTLM or Kerberos MS Office asks for credentials only 1 time during first document access.
- Implement Office Forms Based Authentication Protocol (MS-OFBA).
- Implement Url-authentiation. Your urls will look like:
  `http://webdavserver.com/[SessionID1234567890]/path/file.docx`

  Make sure you do not include the session ID in query string, Microsoft Office will truncate it. You will have to put session ID somewhere in the path, as in the above example, which is not very convenient, when you need to mount a WebDAV folder in you file system, but still works in most cases.

Comment: Any comments what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: The #1 advantage is that WebDAV is an open protocol, based on standards, well documented and used in many CMS/DMS/CRM. Some disadvantage - it is XML-based (you can not use Json or anything else) and some times pretty complex (for example ACL and CalDAV are non- trivial).

Comment: Thank you sir for your insight, helps one understand why it would be beneficial to utilize WebDAV in developing socially minded technologies :)

Comment: Has anyone implemented "Office Forms Based Authentication Protocol (MS-OFBA)" this please help me on this. My requirement is same as want to remove credentials prompt when accessing webdav url from ms office